# Amazon Route 53 Domain Suddenly Parked?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, nameservers

Recently, I registered a domain with Amazon Route 53, which I successfully pointed to my EC2 Instance.  It was working well for a while, then suddenly reverted to a *Parked Domain* page, looking like so;

[image]

The EC2 instance is still running, and I can access it successfully using its public IP address, which does indeed match my A Record in my Hosted Zones of Route 53.

Is there somewhere else that the proper name servers or DNS must be updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your email.  If you didn't verify your email in 15 days as required, this is a potential result.

> Q. Who is Gandi?
>
> Amazon is a reseller of the registrar Gandi. As the registrar of record, Gandi is required by ICANN to contact the registrant to verify their contact information at the time of initial registration. You MUST verify your contact information if requested by Gandi within the first 15 days of registration in order to prevent your domain name from being suspended. Gandi also sends out reminder notices before the domain comes up for renewal.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/

Comment: Thanks for your response!  While I never did receive any e-mail to verify the domain, this eventually resolved itself.  It was simply strange this occurred after functioning normally for so long.  Thank you!